# What is the issue with this conditional variable implementation?

Tags: c++

I've implemented code to call a service API every 10 seconds using a c++ client. Most of the times I've noticed it is around 10 seconds but occassionally I see an issue like below where it look longer. I'm using conditional variable on wait_until. What's wrong with my implementation? Any ideas? 
Here's the timing output:

```
currentDateTime()=2015-12-21.15:13:21
currentDateTime()=2015-12-21.15:13:57
```

And the code:

```
void client::runHeartbeat() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(lock);
    for (;;) {
        // check the current time
        auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        /* Set a condition on the conditional variable to wake up the this thread.
           This thread is woken up on 2 conditions:
           1. After a timeout of now + interval when we want to send the next heartbeat
           2. When the client is destroyed. 
           */
        shutdownHeartbeat.wait_until(locker, now + std::chrono::milliseconds(sleepMillis));
        // After waking up we want to check if a sign-out has occurred.
        if (m_heartbeatRunning) {

            std::cout << "currentDateTime()=" << currentDateTime() <<   std::endl;
            SendHeartbeat();
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You do know about `std::condition_variable` ?

Comment: We have to see what else holds this lock.

Comment: You have no guarantee on the amount of time that will pass except that it will be *at least* the time you have asked for.

Comment: @David Schwartz This is the only part of the code that is using this lock

Comment: If you only want to put your ther to sleep, why do you use a lock and acondition variable instead of `std::this_thread::sleep_for` ?

Comment: i want to sleep this thread for 10 seconds but I also want to check if someone signed out when I wake up after 10 seconds. So I want to stop running this thread until 10 seconds or till someone signs out.

Comment: Is it possible, that SendHeartbeat() blocks on something? We really need to see more of your code

Comment: So there is someone using the condition variable, but not the lock - correct?

Comment: Yes .. the condition variable can be notified by a SignOut API call

Comment: Is `m_heartbeatRunning` an atomic variable?

Comment: Yes it is defined as std::atomic<bool> m_heartbeatRunning;

Comment: OK, I'll stop guessing around. Please provide a [mcve](/help/mcve) or at least the implementation of all involved functions. Normally, I'd just agree with David Hoelzer's statement, but 30 vs 10 s is a little extreme. In any case, I'd at least replace the wait_until with a `wait_for`

Comment: what benefit does wait_for have over wait_until?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98751/discussion-between-mikemb-and-phoenix).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using the high_resolution_clock for your needs. system_clock is not guaranteed a high resolution, so that may be a part of the problem.

Note that it's definition is implementation dependent so you might just get a typedef back onto system_clock on some compilers.

Comment: You really think, there is an implementation of system_clock, that has a resolution of less than a second?

Comment: @MikeMB Maybe not `system_clock`, but there is one for `high_resolution_clock`. I know at least `g++` and MinGW-64w has one that goes to the milliseconds if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: My statement might have been unclear. If I read the output in the question correctly, then the period was 36s instead of 10s. This can't be a res problem and to observably affect the result at all, the resolution of `system_clock` would have to be in the range of seconds. So far I haven't seen any clock function (be it a c-function or from the chrono header) that was that bad.I'd expect any non-embedded implementation of `system_clock` to have a resolution (or rather tick length) of a microsecond or better (I'm not sure, whether this is true for older versions of VC++ though).

Comment: @MikeMB Oh silly me, it's seconds, not milliseconds over there. Thanks.